# python-bitcoinrpc: only DEBUG available?

Tags: python

I'm starting with [python-bitcoinrpc](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) from J.Garzik.

I'm using to try it the code provided by James D'Angelo (from Bitcoin 101 on youtube):

Apparently, there were some major changes with python-bitcoinrpc, not taken into account by old tutorial as the ones from James since you don't do now:

```
from bitcoinrpc.util import *
from bitcoinrpc.exceptions import *
from bitcoinrpc.__init__ import *
from bitcoinrpc.config import *
from bitcoinrpc.proxy import *
from bitcoinrpc.data import *
from bitcoinrpc.connection import *

bitcoin = connect_to_local()
NEW_ADDRESS = bitcoin.getnewaddress()
print(NEW_ADDRESS)
```

But now:

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy

access = AuthServiceProxy() 
info = access.getinfo() # Not WORKING: info is None
```

That's okay for me, and very shorter.

The problem is to get `access.getinfo()`to a variable? According to the README from python-bitcoinrpc, you can use the logging module to print stderr to the screen

```
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger("BitcoinRPC").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"%(rpc_user, rpc_password))
print(rpc_connection.getinfo())
```

But how do you put that into a variable??
Like with:

`info = access.getinfo()`
(which is not working: `info`is `None`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there's a bug in the pip version of python-bitcoinrpc...

use `pip install git+https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc.git` instead.